# Django gets all checkboxes values, checked or un-checked

Tags: django, forms, checkbox

Using Django's `User` model, I have the following template:

**UPDATE**: more detailed template

```
<form method=POST action="...">
  <table>
    ...
    {% for account in accounts %}
      <tr>
        <td>
          {{ account.username }}
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type=checkbox name=account value="{{ account.id }}" {% if account.is_active %}checked{% endif %}>
        </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
<input type=submit value=Submit>
</form>

{% for pg in paginator.page_range %}
  {% if queryset.number == pg %}
    <li><span>{{ pg }}</span></li>
  {% else %}
    <li><a href=".../?page={{ pg }}">{{ pg }}</a></li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

which shows the status of each account and the user may update them.

**UPDATE**: including GET and POST handling. As there are thousands of accounts, they are displayed using Django's `pagination`.

In the `views`:

```
def account(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        users = User.objects.all()
        paginator = Paginator(users, 30)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        accounts = paginator.page(page)
        ...

        return render(request, 'account/account.html', {'accounts':accounts, 'paginator':paginator}

    # POST
    accounts = request.POST.getlist('account')    # This will get only the `checked` ones
    for account in User.objects.filter(id__in=accounts):
        if account is checked:    # Only hypothetical ...
            account.is_active = True
        else:
            account.is_active = False
        account.save()
    return redirect(...)
```

Questions:

1. How do I retrieve **ALL** checkboxes, checked or un-checked?
2. How can the retrieved list contains the status of each account, so that I can set the account's `is_active` field accordingly?

Comment: please update your full views contain with that function.. I need to know your context of `accounts`..

Comment: The question is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** To get un-checked, you can using `.exclude`

```
User.objects.exclude(id__in=accounts)
```

more specify;

```
account_ids = [u.id for u in User.objects.exclude(id__in=accounts)]
```

**2.** set the account's as `is_active` or not.

```
User.objects.filter(id__in=accounts).update(is_active=True)
User.objects.exclude(id__in=accounts).update(is_active=False)
```

I think what exacly you need to do is: 
If accounts is checked then set to `is_active=True` and the others `is_active=False`, that's your point right?

So, this a suggestion from me;

```
def account(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    template_name = 'account/account.html'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        account_ids = request.POST.getlist('account')

        users.filter(id__in=account_ids).update(is_active=True)
        users.exclude(id__in=account_ids).update(is_active=False)

        return redirect(...)

    paginator = Paginator(users, 30)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    accounts = paginator.page(page)
    ....

    context = {'accounts': accounts, 'paginator': paginator}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```