# Django - How to get checked objects in template checkboxes?

Tags: python, html, django, web-development-server

Im new in Django,
I'm using xhtml2pdf for rendering data objects from template to PDF file , and i want to allow users to render only checked objects by checkboxes into pdf, is there anyway to filter that in Django ?

Thanks

views.py :

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode('ISO-8859-1')), result, link_callback=link_callback)
    if pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse('Error')
    return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')



class ViewPDF(View):
    @method_decorator(login_required(login_url='livraison:login_page')) 
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        checked_objects = [i dont know how to get them]
        queryset = Livraison.objects.filter(id__in=[checked_objects])  # i want something does that
        data = {
            'livraisons' : queryset,  
            'now' : f'Livraisons-{date.today()}'  
        }
        pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf_template.html', data)
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

Comment: check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47245598/django-gets-all-checkboxes-values-checked-or-un-checked hope it will help

Comment: @KumarSinha the request.POST.getlist i tried it before, it does not return any result i think because GET method is used for this function , idk anyway thanks for commenting

Answer (score 0):

use forms to get user data.

```
class LivraisonSelectForm(forms.Form):
   livraison = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='select', queryset=Livraison.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxInput())
```

then use it in your view:

```
class ViewPDF(FormView):
    form_class = LivraisonSelectForm
    template_name = 'path_to_template_with_html_to_filter_data'

    @method_decorator(login_required(login_url='livraison:login_page')) 
    def form_valid(self, form):
        checked_objects = form.cleaned_data.get('livraison', [])
        queryset = Livraison.objects.filter(id__in=checked_objects)  # i want something does that
        data = {
            'livraisons' : queryset,  
            'now' : f'Livraisons-{date.today()}'  
        }
        pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf_template.html', data)
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

and don't forget to show this form in your html `{{ form }}`

Comment: forms has not ModelSelectField ?!
and i already used forms 
`code`
class LivraisonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Livraison
        exclude = ('checked',)

Comment: my bad it's called `ModelChoiceField`. changed in answer

Comment: do i have change my form class completely ?!

Comment: how can i say for sure if you don't include your forms(and view which generate choices) into your question ?

Comment: i changed inheriting class from View to FormView now and it returns no data..

Answer (score 0):

**

> **UPDATE**

**

I Found a solution , i used Ajax code to collect every selected object

```
 // check selected objects (#pdf is the id of the button which gonna generate the pdf file)
            $('#pdf').click(function () {
                var id = [];

                $(':checkbox:checked').each(function (i) {
                    id[i] = $(this).val()
                })
                if (id.length === 0) {
                    alert('Please Select something..');
                } else {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '.',
                        method: 'GET',
                        data: {
                            id,
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            console.log('PDF is ready')
                        }
                    })
                }

            });
```

then i ad the variable into the view function to collect the selected objects and filter the queryset

```
myFunction.selected_ones = request.GET.getlist('id[]')
```

then filter queryset in the generated_pdf_func

```
queryset = MODEL.objects.filter(id__in=[x for x in myFunction.selected_ones if x != '0'])
```

NOTE : <if x != '0'> is important in case you want to select all because it returns 0 and you don't have any id = 0 in the DB